# Combine RepeatedStratifiedKFold and crossval

Tags: python, cross-validation

Is it okay to combine RepeatedStratifiedKFold and cross_val_score?

The result in the example below are 30 accuracy values (3x10 splits).
How to calculate the final accuracy value for the 3 times 10 fold cv?

```
cv = RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, n_repeats=3, random_state=rand)
rf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=e, random_state=rand)
scores = cross_val_score(rf, data, Y, scoring='accuracy', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a recent paper dealing with repeated cross-validation:

[On estimating model accuracy with repeated cross-validation](https://lirias.kuleuven.be/1655861)

It states: If $A_i$ is the result returned by a single k-fold crossvalidation, then
the cross-validation result for the whole repeated cross-validation (n repeats) is: $A = \frac{\sum_i A_i}{n}$.

So to calculate the final score, we need a "chunks" function: ([Code from stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks))

```
def chunks(lst, n):
    means = []
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        means.append(np.mean(lst[i:i + n]))
    return means
```

Then the final score can be calculated by:

```
np.mean(chunks(scores, n_splits))
```

Comment: I don't think you need the chunks here, since averaging (lists of the same size) is linear: the average of the averages is just the average of all the scores.

Comment: You are right, for $A_i = \frac{1}{10}(A_{i1}+ ... A_{i10})$ it follows that $\frac{1}{3} (A_1+A_2+A_3) = \frac{1}{30} \sum_{i=1}^{3} \sum_{j=1}^{10} A_{ij}$